# Why does a copy operation to a directory that serves as a mountpoint not copy the data to the mounted drive?

Tags: mount, partition, hard-disk, fstab

### Why does a copy operation to a directory that serves as a mountpoint not copy the data to the mounted drive?

I bought a 2 terabyte drive and mounted it in a subdirectory within my home directory.

Where `/dev/sdb` is my 500GB system drive and `/dev/sda` is my 2TB data drive:

```
Partition        Mountpoint
/dev/sdb1   ->   /
/dev/sdb3   ->   /home
/dev/sdb2   ->   swap
/dev/sda1   ->   /home/data
```

This all *seems* to work, and even shows up in `df -h` properly (i.e., `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/home/data` [to regenerate the fstab I booted into my arch disk live environment and mounted the partitions to the folders in `/mnt` that I wanted to partition, running `genfstab -U /mnt > /mnt/etc/fstab`; it worked])

Last night I set my box to running a 650GB copy operation to `/home/data`. Imagine my surprise when tons of copy operations failed due to being out of diskspace.

`df -h` shows that `/dev/sdb3` is full but `/dev/sda1` is nearly empty (77MB). The mount point is functioning properly, so far as I can tell, but the copy operation put all the data in `/dev/sdb3`! Presumably, if I unmount the drive, the music will still be in `/home/data`.

Clearly there is something about mounting and fstab that I am not fully understanding.

The particular entry in fstab reads:

```
# /dev/sdb1
UUID=<UUID>    /            ext4     rw,relatime 01

# /dev/sdb3
UUID=<UUID>    /home        ext4     rw,relatime 02

# /dev/sda1
UUID=<UUID>    /home/data   ext4     rw,relatime 02
```

Before regenerating the fstab, I had a swap entry in fstab. I'm not sure why it didn't regenerate.

### Update: I managed to get the output of `mount`:

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4051032k,nr_inodes=1012758,mode=755)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=44,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13569)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
/dev/sdb3 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /home/data type ext4 (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=811560k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Comment: Are you sure the quoted `fstab` is correct? It also mounts `sdb3` under `/home/data` although that is your `/home` partition.

Comment: Whoops. I copied it from the screen rather than from the computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm at work now, so if this is something that requires a lot more information and isn't simply a known quirk, I'm going to have to wait to post more data.

Comment: Please verify your mounts by adding the output of `mount` to your question.

Comment: @Hermann I managed to get it.

Comment: what's the command you're using to copy the data?

Comment: @TimKennedy Since I'm copying from an external drive: `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt` and then `sudo cp -r /mnt/music data/` when I'm in `~`.

Comment: Please note: the music directory with it's contents actually did end up in `/home/data`. I checked. It's just that `df -h` seems to imply that all of the data is actually on `/dev/sdb3` and the plethora of copy errors state it pretty matter-of-factly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that your copy command is `cp -r /mnt/music data/` when you're in `~`.

This means that you're copying your data into `/home/<username>/data`, since `~` would expand to `/home/username`.

However, your external drive is mounted as `/home/data`, according to the `mount` output you supplied.  To finish your goal, you need to do two things:

- copy all the data from `/home/<username/data` to the `/home/data` directory.

  - `rsync -avHP /home/<username>/data/* /home/data/` (or some variation)
  - this moves all the data out of your home partition and into the external drive.
- fix up how you want to access the drive

  - leave it mounted as `/home/data`, and just access it that way
  - one option would be to create a symlink in `~` to access it: `ln -s /home/data ~/data`
  - another option would be to edit your fstab to set the mountpoint for the external drive to `/home/<username>/data`

Comment: Holy cow Tim. Thank you so much. PEBCAK. I knew there was something horrifically stupid I was overlooking.

Comment: We've all been there, @malan.  That's why makes this site (and the other StackExchange sites) so valuable.